# C# Values erased when Class is called

Tags: arrays, class, integer

I have a class with a public integer array declared at the top of the class like so:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    class vInfo
    {
        public int[] some_int = new int[10]

        public void Somevoid()
        {
            some_int[0] = 100; // 
        }

        public void NewVoid()
        {
            messagebox.show(some_int[0].ToString()); // Returns '0'
        }
    }
}
```

**From Form 1:**

```
vInfo VI = new vInfo();

VI.somevoid;
VI.newvoid
```

I call the class twice, after calling the class a second time the previously assigned value resets back to `0`. Anyone have any ideas on the matter?

Comment: What do you mean by calling the class twice? Are you creating two different instances?

Comment: There are some syntax errors, like missing ; but I think I understand what you are asking and I think the code should work. Can you cut and paste the exact code from your project so we aren't distracted by what I assume are typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `new vInfo()`, you're creating a brand new instance of the class with a brand new array.